# iOS:set scrollPosition to `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle` it did not scroll to correct position

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview

This is my code below:

```
 if (![self.cityLabel.text isEqualToString:@""] && dataOfCity.count != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataOfCity.count; i ++) {

            if ([dataOfCity[i] isEqualToString:self.cityLabel.text]) {

                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                [_tab_city selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
            }
        }

    }
```

And the `result` is the picture which is not in the middle of the tableView below :

[image: The result picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I have found my question's reason:

I do that code before `uiview animation`, so it will show that wrong place,
I replace those code to the `completion block`,so the issue resolved:

```
- (void)show{

    if (self.isOpenState == YES ) {
        return;
    }



    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        //CGRect frame = self.backOfTabAndTrailer.frame;
        self.opacity_back.alpha = 0.2;

        //frame.size.height = _rowHeight * _numberOfRow;
        //[self.backOfTabAndTrailer setFrame:frame];

        self.backOfTabAndTrailer.frame = CGRectMake(_backOfTabAndTrailer.frame.origin.x, _backOfTabAndTrailer.frame.origin.y, _backOfTabAndTrailer.frame.size.width, _rowHeight * _numberOfRow);
        self.tab_province.frame = CGRectMake(self.tab_province.frame.origin.x, self.tab_province.frame.origin.y, self.tab_province.frame.size.width, _rowHeight * _numberOfRow);
        self.tab_city.frame = CGRectMake(self.tab_city.frame.origin.x, self.tab_city.frame.origin.y, self.tab_city.frame.size.width, _rowHeight * _numberOfRow);
        self.tab_country.frame = CGRectMake(self.tab_country.frame.origin.x, self.tab_country.frame.origin.y, self.tab_country.frame.size.width, _rowHeight * _numberOfRow);
        self.trailerView.frame = CGRectMake(_backOfTabAndTrailer.frame.origin.x, _rowHeight * _numberOfRow, self.trailerView.frame.size.width, Height_Of_Trailer);
        self.trailerImage.frame = CGRectMake(_allFrame.size.width / 2 - Height_Of_Trailer / 2, 0, Height_Of_Trailer, Height_Of_Trailer);
        self.trail_line.frame = CGRectMake(self.backOfTabAndTrailer.frame.origin.x, 0, self.trail_line.frame.size.width, 1);
        self.trailerButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backOfTabAndTrailer.frame.origin.x, 0, self.trailerButton.frame.size.width, 1);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        self.isOpenState = YES;

        /* 让tabview滚到被选中的地方 */
        if (![self.provinceLabel.text isEqualToString:@""] && dataOfProvince.count != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataOfProvince.count; i ++) {

                if ([dataOfProvince[i] isEqualToString:self.provinceLabel.text]) {

                    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                    [_tab_province selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
                }
            }

        }
        if (![self.cityLabel.text isEqualToString:@""] && dataOfCity.count != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataOfCity.count; i ++) {

                if ([dataOfCity[i] isEqualToString:self.cityLabel.text]) {

                    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                    [_tab_city selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
                }
            }

        }
        if (![self.countryLabel.text isEqualToString:@""] && dataOfCountry.count != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataOfCountry.count; i ++) {

                if ([dataOfCountry[i] isEqualToString:self.countryLabel.text]) {

                    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                    [_tab_country selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
                }
            }

        }

    }];



}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I think I understand what happens: 
the table view is already performing another animation and the scrollToRowAtIndexPath is ignored. 
Wrapping the method in CATransaction block works for me (swift code):

    CATransaction.begin()

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(cell.indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
    tableView.endUpdates()

    CATransaction.commit()

    Another solution that worked for me was using performSelectorWithDelay, with the delay being long enough for other animations on the table view to finish.
```